# Wireless keyboard for mac keeps losing connection

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth

My wireless keyboard for mac keeps on losing connection from mac. It automatically gets disconnected and gets connected again. I have gone through multiple threads here on SE and also on apple forums and I have tried following things so far:

1. Removed the keyboard from list of bluetooth devices and tried adding it back
2. Removed bluetooth plist file
3. Did SMC reset
4. I also bought a new keyboard thinking that it could be an issue with my existing keyboard, which is not the case.
5. My keyboard battery is 100%

Is there anything else that I can try to deal with this issue?

Comment: You've already ruled out the issue being the keyboard by trying a new keyboard. I would also try and rule out Bluetooth (driver/hardware/software) on the device by checking if a wireless mouse or a wireless headset stays connected or has a similar issue.

Comment: I already have a wireless trackpad and from what I can see, I do not have much issue with it. It is very intriguing that all the wireless keyboard do have this issue while trackpad does not have this issue.

Comment: What model mac? Is there anything metallic between the mac and your keyboard? Are the keyboard and mac sitting at the same height with a clear line of sight between them?

Comment: Is your mac on the current macOS version?
Are there any other bluetooth devices / laptops / phones near which could try to connect to the keyboard?

Comment: It's Mojave 10.14.6. There is apple trackpad, iPhone and a Bluetooth headphone on the desk the headphone is mostly off.

Comment: USB 3 and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi can cause issues with Bluetooth. Do you have a USB hub or connection next to your Mac? Is your Wi-Fi router close to the computer?

Comment: I do. It have a WiFi near by. I do have a usb switch next to the machine though. Let me try moving usb switch a little bit farther..

Comment: Actully, it is 1 foot away and due to the cable length limitation, it is as far as it can go.

Comment: I have same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Connect a wired USB keyboard / Mouse to the Mac (most any USB keyboard will do).  While holding Option + Shift click on the Bluetooth menu bar icon.  Go to Debug.  There is an an option to reset the Bluetooth module as well as factory resetting Apple Bluetooth devices.

1. Make sure your Mac is up-to-date with macOS and all updates
2. Charge the Apple Bluetooth devices fully
3. Perform the SMC Reset first
4. Reset the Bluetooth Module under the Bluetooth Debug menu (holding Option + Shift while clicking Bluetooth menu bar item)
5. Factory Reset the Apple Bluetooth Devices (Keyboard, etc.)
6. Re-pair the Apple Bluetooth devices from scratch

Check for any nearby devices that might be putting out a radio signal or EMF (Electro-Magnetic Field) Such as motorized fan, space heater, an old monitor, a radio transmitter, etc. Move them away from the Mac and your bluetooth devices. Don't plug them into the same power strip, etc. Check for other devices plugged into the Mac such as 3rd party docking stations, especially ones not actually certified by Apple (HP, etc.) try disconnecting them for awhile see if the problem goes away.

The Mac Mini M1 was plagued by bluetooth issues on Big Sur prior to 11.3.x. Latest release fixed all the bluetooth issues. Recommend using a tool such as SilentKnight to verify your firmware is up-to-date. There have been issues with Mac's updating macOS but failing to update the firmware. SilentKnight will let you know if you are missing the appropriate firmware update among other security updates.  You can find the free SilentKnight on the Eclectic Light Company website. https://eclecticlight.co make sure you search the site for "bluetooth" there are several blogs talking about disconnect issues and tooling to help trouble-shooting. Some USB3 devices have been known to disrupt Bluetooth. When connecting USB 3 devices to a USB-C port, Apple recommends using the front port on the left-hand side, or any USB-C port on the right side of the Mac. Use a longer USB-C cable and move the USB3 device further away from the antenna's for Wi-Fi / Bluetooth. Apple has a Wi-Fi and Bluetooth support page https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201542

Comment: Note: this doesn't work in Monterrey as they've removed the shift+option click debug menu.  You'd have to reset it the other way - deleting the plist .

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Apple AirPods or other Bluetooth devices connected to the Mac? Try limiting the amount of Bluetooth device list to a mouse and keyboard and see if one of your other devices could be causing some sort of interference.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the other answers here didn't work. I navigated to  `~/Library/Preferences` and found the bluetooth plist and deleted it.

I had to search for Bluetooth within this folder to find it. After restarting I went to *Preferences* and forgot my keyboard and then re-paired. I also had duplicate pairing for my AirPods so I deleted one of those too. After doing this and restarting the problem finally went away.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happens mostly when I charge one of my devices. I have a Magic Trackpad and a Keyboard lying around. Then for some reason, only the one connected via USB is connected.

**What does help for me:**

Go to the Bluetooth settings, disable Bluetooth, and enable it again. Sometimes I also have to explicitly tap on "Connect" for one of the devices.

Not sure why it's losing connection but that's way faster (and safer) compared to fiddling around in some system files.